# Improving Speed of lang detect on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I'm facing a problem regarding speed. I am detecting languages in a pandas dataframe, however since I'm passing considerable amount of data, it gets slow ... Actually the issue even is worse because it runs faster on a Jupyter Notebook than on a script, and I'd like to get the script running on the cloud, so a notebook won't really work for what I want.

```
from langdetect import detect
import pandas  as pd 
import time 


sup = {"Source":['Hello I am ','Who are you again?','Please be carefull ..','What are you         doing?','I love cookies'],
            "Target": ['Olá eu sou','Quem és tu ? ', 'Tem cuidado','Que estás a fazer ?','Eu gosto de bolachinhas']}

df = pd.DataFrame(sup)

df = pd.concat([df]*1000, ignore_index=True)


print(len(df))



print(df.head())

start = time.time()


df['detected_source'] = list(map(lambda x: detect(x), df['Source']))
df['detected_target'] = list(map(lambda x: detect(x), df['Target']))

print(df.head())
print("\n")


print("Duration is {} secdonds".format(time.time() - start ))
start = time.time()
print("\n")

df['detected_source1'] = df['Source'].apply(detect)
df['detected_final1'] = df['Target'].apply(detect)

print(df.head())

print("\n")


print("Duration is {} secdonds".format(time.time() - start ))
```

And I get the following output:

Duration is 44.70115399360657 secdonds

Duration is 44.82259392738342 secdonds

Is there a way of making this faster?

PS: This first code runs okay in Jupyter, however it's slow outside of it, last time I ran it even halted, maybe I have a bug in my script that I don't have in jupyter, does jupyter use a different interpreter?

I am running Windows but I'm using WSL with ubuntu with VSCODE, jupyter is ran on Windows with Anaconda!

Many thanks!

Have an amazing day!